# In Pandas, merge two dataframes with complex multi-indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to merge two dataframes on columns Name and Depth.  The depth in the left df has a single depth column ('depth').  However, the right df has two depth columns ('top_depth' and 'bottom_depth').

I would like the take each record from the left df and, if available, assign a record from the right df if 'depth' falls between 'top_depth' and 'bottom_depth'.

I've put together some simple dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['b1', 4, 9],
    ['b1', 5, 61],
    ['b1', 15, 95],
    ['b1', 24, 9],
    ['b2', 4, 5],
    ['b2', 6, 6],
    ['b2', 44, 0]]),
    columns=['name', 'depth', 'attr1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['b1', 1, 6, 66],
    ['b1', 14, 16, 99],
    ['b1', 51, 55, 9],
    ['b3', 0, 5, 32]]),
    columns=['name', 'top_depth', 'bottom_depth', 'attr2'])
```

Then merge to get this:

```
>>> df3
  name depth top_depth bottom_depth attr1 attr2
0   b1   4.0       1.0          6.0   9.0  66.0
1   b1   5.0       1.0          6.0  61.0  66.0
2   b1  15.0      14.0         16.0  95.0  99.0
3   b1    24       NaN          NaN     9   NaN
4   b2     4       NaN          NaN     5   NaN
5   b2     6       NaN          NaN     6   NaN
6   b2    44       NaN          NaN     0   NaN
```

I am sure I could figure out a brute force approach to this, but there has gotta be a better, more pandas, way of doing this.

Comment: What happened to the b3 in row 3 (of df2) ?

Comment: Why is df2['top_depth'] - df2['bottom_depth'] not consistently positive or negative?

Comment: Liam you caught my error.  Third row in df2 (row 2) should be 51, 55 not 55, 51.  I've edited my question.  Thank you.  df2['bottom_depth'] - df2['top_depth'] should always be positive.

Comment: Andy, there is no b3 in df1 so it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (on the index):

```
In [11]: df1.join(df2, how='outer', rsuffix='_')
Out[11]:
  name depth attr1 name_ top_depth bottom_depth attr2
0   b1     4     9    b1         1            6    66
1   b1     5    61    b1        14           16    99
2   b1    15    95    b1        55           51     9
3   b1    24     9    b3         0            5    32
4   b2     4     5   NaN       NaN          NaN   NaN
5   b2     6     6   NaN       NaN          NaN   NaN
6   b2    44     0   NaN       NaN          NaN   NaN
```

*Note: the rsuffix is required since the name columns do not match... it's not clear what you would want to do with this case.*

---

*Note: the `np.array` forces the arrays to share the (initial?) datatype, in this case this means that all the numbers are strings. You can pass a plain python list to DataFrame!*

Here's a slightly inefficient method, first have function which looks up the name and checks that the depth is within top and bottom:

```
def get_depth_group(name, depth):
    arr = (df2.name == name) & (df2.bottom_depth > depth) & (depth > df2.top_depth)
    return df2.iloc[arr.argmax()] if any(arr) else np.nan
```

*It may be more efficient to use a different data structure for this... but this'll work!*

```
In [21]: df1[['depth', 'attr1']].join(df1.apply(lambda x: get_depth_group(x['name'], x['depth']), axis=1))
Out[21]:
   depth  attr1 name  top_depth  bottom_depth  attr2
0      4      9   b1          1             6     66
1      5     61   b1          1             6     66
2     15     95   b1         14            16     99
3     24      9  NaN        NaN           NaN    NaN
4      4      5  NaN        NaN           NaN    NaN
5      6      6  NaN        NaN           NaN    NaN
6     44      0  NaN        NaN           NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['b1', 4, 9],
    ['b1', 5, 61],
    ['b1', 15, 95],
    ['b1', 24, 9],
    ['b2', 4, 5],
    ['b2', 6, 6],
    ['b2', 44, 0]]),
    columns=['name', 'depth', 'attr1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['b1', 1, 6, 66],
    ['b1', 14, 16, 99],
    ['b1', 51, 55, 9],
    ['b3', 0, 5, 32]]),
    columns=['name', 'top_depth', 'bottom_depth', 'attr2'])

om = pd.ordered_merge(df2, df1)
om = om.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) 
sandwiched = om.query('(depth > top_depth) & (depth <= bottom_depth)')
```

sandwiched is:

> ```
>   name  top_depth  bottom_depth  attr2  depth  attr1
> 0   b1          1             6     66      4      9
> 1   b1          1             6     66      5     61
> 6   b1         14            16     99     15     95
> ```

And I think you can attach the rest of df1 using a `join` I can't remember.

It might not be a SQL-shaped problem after all -- can you assume they're sorted by depth and top_depth? And do df2 ranges overlap? Iterating through each dataframe once might be the efficient way.